# Unable to include repository from maven central to my gradle project

Tags: gradle

I am learning to use Eclipse to build Gradle projects. When I try to include a repository from the Maven central, I am unable to do so. While the following code works in Maven,

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.1</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
      <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.10.4</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This is not working in Gradle:

```
dependencies {
   compile "joda-time:joda-time:2.2"
   compile "org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:4.10.4"
}
```

Comment: What is not working? How is it not working? Why do you use elasticsearch in your Maven config, and joda-time in your gradle config? You do realize they're not the same thing, I guess? Have you told gradle that you wanted to download artefacts from Maven Central?

Comment: @rajaIIT, does my answer solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is not working? You didn't add the `repositories` block thus gradle probably has no place to download the files. Here's how it should be configured:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
   compile "joda-time:joda-time:2.2"
   compile "org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:4.10.4"
}

task copyDeps(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'deps'
}
```

`copyDeps` task is added only to check if it all works.